# Dropbox-like client for CMIS?

Tags: sparkleshare, cmis

Many of my users have their files on one big [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) server.

PROBLEM: They can not use their files while not connected to the Internet.

QUESTION: Is there a Dropbox-like software for CMIS?

- When connected, pushes local changes to the server
- When connected, polls the server every *n* minutes to pull changes
- Cross-platform (Linux, Mac, Windows, maybe Android?)
- Ability to check out only a part of the repository
- Preferably open source
- Dropbox-like UI is perfect but other UI concepts are welcome too

For instance, [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org) is like DropBox for [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29).
*CMIS is a document transfer protocol used by Alfresco, Sharepoint, EMC, Filenet, OpenText, Lotus, ...*

Comment: Here is a discussion about creating such a tool: https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=42158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 8 months of searching I still haven't found any Dropbox-like client for CMIS, so I created one: [CmisSync](http://CmisSync.com)

[image]

Available on Windows and Linux, soon Mac. Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Drive 3 has a CMIS connector and offline functionality (untested). Available for Mac and Windows.

http://www.adobe.com/products/adobedrive.html

Comment: Nice! I could not find the price... There is a "Student & teacher pricing" button but no pricing info anywhere... maybe it is just free? I don't have any Windows or Mac to test and see whether it requires payment at install or something... would you happen to know whether it is free or not? Thanks!

Comment: From reading the doc, it does not seem to allow one to edit offline documents while disconnected from the network: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/adobedrive/CMIS_Connector_TechNote.pdf Where have you seen this offline feature? Thanks!